# Multiple Applications SSO oauth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

I am trying to figure out how to perform single sign on with OAUTH2 on two different applications. Currently according  to my understanding I can use the Authentication Provider in order to authenticate my clients. The procedure is the following:

1. The client is redirected to the Authentication Provider
2. Then the client is loggedin and has the code
3. The client provides the code to my application
4. The server uses the code in  order to retrieve the access token.
5. Using the access token my server uses the remote API to retrieve information

Now I have a second application in a different backend (PHP) that I want to inform that the user is already loged in via the OAUTH. My naive solution is to provide the access token of the first application to the second  application in order to perform the authentication. However, I understand that I  am not allowed to share the access tokens between apps.

Answer (score 0):

Every backend service should validate the access token via introspection. The only introspection guarantees that the token is valid, not expired or revoked.

So you have to pass the access token to the Backend service. To secure that you can use HTTPS API.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct regarding not sharing the access token. The Authentication Provider should also allow creating an ID token. You would configure your second application with the authentication provider and get a client id. Both the client id and ID token are required to sign in the second app which will generate it's access token.

What grant type are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Both apps need to redirect the user:

- In the first app the user will authenticate and the app will get an access token scoped to that app.
- In the second app the user will be automatically signed in without needing to reauthenticate. The app will then get a separate access token, generally with different privileges to that of the first app.

This is standard SSO behaviour and it is best to accept it. Usability is pretty good. Trying to share tokens is not advised unless you have advanced requirements.